# How do I pass an object from a subscription into the actual variable in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, subscription

I'm trying to pass the data I get from a subscription into a local variable but every time i `console.log(the local object)`   it returns undefined, but when I `console.log(data from the subscription)` the data is correctly returned. I need the object in the local variable to access the parameters from the html template.

I have this method in an angular service

```
export class MachinesService {

apiURL: string = environment.apiURL + 'Machine/';

constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

public getMachine(id: number): Observable<IMachine> {return this.http.get<IMachine>(this.apiURL + ${id})}}
```

In the app component I receive the id from the router snapshot and I call the service method with that id, I tried different ways.

First this:

```
export class MachineViewComponent implements OnInit { 
redirect: string | null = null;

machine?: IMachine ; 
machineId? : number;

constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private machinesService : MachinesService,
    private router : Router ) { } 

ngOnInit(): void {
 this.machineId = parseInt( this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get("id")!); this.machinesService.getMachine(this.machineId!).subscribe(data => { this.machine = data; })
 }

}
```

then this:

```
export class MachineViewComponent implements OnInit {
    redirect: string | null = null;

 subscription: Subscription[] = [];
 machine?: IMachine ;
 machineId? : number;

    constructor(
        private route: ActivatedRoute ,
        private machinesService : MachinesService, 
        private router : Router ) { }

    ngOnInit(): void { 
        this.machineId = parseInt( this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get("id")!);
        this.RefreshData(); 
    }

    RefreshData() {
    this.subscription.push(this.machinesService.getMachine(this.machineId!).subscribe(data =>{
    this.machine = data;
       })) 
    };

}
```

and also this way:

```
export class MachineViewComponent implements OnInit { 
    redirect: string | null = null;
    
    machine?: IMachine ; 
    machineId? : number;

    constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute , 
    private machinesService : MachinesService, 
    private router : Router ) { }

    ngOnInit(): void { 
    this.machineId = parseInt( this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get("id")!);
    let GetMachineAsync = async (machineId : number): Promise<any> =>{
        const machinex  = await
        this.machinesService.getMachine(this.machineId!).subscribe(machine => {
            return machine});
        return machinex
    }; 
    GetMachineAsync(this.machineId).then(x => {console.log(x); this.machine = x}) } }
```

Then I ran out of ideas

Every time i log this.machine is undefined but the machine element from the subscription is correct.

Also when I look for the http response in the network the object is here.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Just make `this.machineId` an Observable itself. `this.machineId = this.machinesService.getMachine(this.machineId!)`. Then, when you need the id, `subscribe` to `this.machineId`, or `pipe` it if you're only transforming the data to be used later. If the data is fetched asynchronously, you can't safely get the value synchronously like you're trying to do. The data being fetched asynronously makes everything dependent on that data also asynchronous.

Comment: but `machineId` is number i get from the snapshot with `parseInt(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get("id")!)` how can I make it an Observable?

Comment: Sorry, I meant make `machine` an Observable. How are you using `this.machine` after it's fetched? Can you show an example?

Comment: If you mean in the html i use for example `{{machine.machineName}}` to write the name in the DOM

Comment: `this.machine` is undefined before successful network call, after completion of `getMachine()` API call, you can access the data. so use a `*ngIf="machine"` on parent HTML tag where you are using it to avoid any error.

Comment: I just figured out that my ts interface had machine_name parameter, backend response is machineName : |

Answer (score 0):

While the original issue may have been caused by a typo in the name, your code is still subtly broken. If you throttle your network connection for example and force the HTTP request to take longer, your code will likely fail. Your code here only works if the HTTP request happens so quickly that the template hasn't had a chance to render yet.

I would make `machine` an `Observable`, then subscribe to it with an async pipe in the template:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.machine = this.machinesService.getMachine(this.machineId!);
}

// In the template:
{{ (machine | async).machineName }}
```

Now, `machine` can't be accessed before it's been fetched.